# Best way to slice packed array dynamically in constraint?

Tags: constraints, system-verilog

I would like to randomize several packed arrays based on the sliced content of another packed array. The issue I'm having is the slice width is not constant. Here is an example of what I would like to do (though it does not work):

```
class some_class;
  
  rand bit [31:0] full_value;
  rand bit [31:0] upper_masked;
  rand bit [15:0] lower;
  rand int upper_width;
  rand int lower_width;
  
  constraint widths_cnstr {
    upper_width inside {[1:16]};
    lower_width inside {[1:16]};
  }
  
  constraint slice_cnstr {
    upper_masked[31-:upper_width] == full_value[31-:upper_width];
    lower == full_value[31-upper_width -: lower_width];
  }

  function new ();
  endfunction

endclass
```

In the above example, a possible outcome could be:

```
upper_width == 8;
lower_width == 3;
full_value == 32'hABABCDCD;
upper_masked == 32'hAB000000;
lower == 3'h5;
```

With the `upper_masked` constraint, I can replace it with a shift:

```
    upper_masked >> (32 - upper_width) == full_value >> (32 - upper_width);
```

With `lower`, things get a lot more complicated, with the need to generate a dynamic-width mask after shifting, and this is further complicated if the rhs argument also has dynamic slices. Is there a better way to do this with constraints?

In other words, I'm looking for a constraint-based way to say:

```
some_arr[M:N] == other_arr;  // or,
some_arr[M:N] == other_arr[X:Y];
```

Comment: `-: lower_width` and similar are not legal in system verilog. The width must be a constant.

Comment: Does `upper_mask` and `lower` really need to be random variables? Could you use `post_randomize()`?

Comment: Unfortunately I have constraints on both - I need to be able to constrain `upper_mask` and `lower` separately, but then enact certain constraints on the concatenated form `full_value` as well.

Comment: @Serge yes, I am asking for a workaround to this limitation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `let` construct to simplify the slicing and masking.

```
let slice(A,H,L) = A & (32'b2 << H-L) - 1 >> L;
```

Then in your constraints

```
slice(some_arr,M,N) == other_arr;

slice(some_arr,M,N) == slice(other_arr,X,Y);
```

Comment: This wasn't quite working for me - I had to change the construct to `let slice(A,H,L) = A >> L & (32'h2 << H-L) - 1;` - is that what you meant?

Comment: @CantSayIHave, sorry, yes. I didn't test my code. There are a number of similar solutions using shift and masking.